# Using HttpClient to read encrypted URL on Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone, dotnet-httpclient

I was reading a normal URL from my app, and it was working fine with the code:

```
string returnedTaskTResult = await new HttpClient().GetStringAsync(url);
```

then I used a new url, this time encrypted, and now is returning the exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: An invalid request URI was provided.
>   The request URI must either be an absolute URI or BaseAddress must be
>   set.

Why is this happening and how o fix it?

Comment: Do you really mean encrypted, or do you mean encoded?  Can you show the URI?

Comment: I mean encrypted. I have a code with a key to encrypt and decrypt.

Comment: I suspect you are going to have to decrypt it before you can use it.

Comment: but I get the right result from the browser. Is different when I try to get this result from code? Because the encrypt is to "protect" the url during its traffic... makes no sense decrypt before this.

Comment: Is it just the path and query that are being encrypted?  The host is not, correct?

Answer (score 1):

When you use GetStringAsync, you need to use a absolute URI.  It sounds like your encrypted URI is relative.  Try this...

```
var client = new HttpClient() {  BaseAddress = new Uri("http://yourhosthere.com");
}
string returnedTaskTResult = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
```

Comment: Well, I found the problem! My URL was created by concatenated variables, and there was "\0" at the end...

Such small thing made me think that it was something more complicated..

Very thank you, anyway!!